# Pivot table on filtered data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

Is there a way to run a pivot table on an Excel sheet that already has columns filtered?

Thus far, I've had to manually copy and paste the sheet into another sheet and then run a filter on that.

Is there an alternative way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: I just understood what you actually meant, and no, I don't think that's possible to directly create a pivottable on the filtered contents of a worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

The Pivot Table will always pull the unfiltered data for its source.

You can cheat a bit by creating a Table from your Source sheet.  Then as you add columns to your Pivot, they should bring the Table filtering that you've already done with them.

Also, you can then filter the data directly in the Pivot Table.  Depending upon your data source, you could pre-filter the data before it gets to Excel. I do this fequently using SQL as a data source and writing a view that pre-filters data before importing.

Comment: I tried creating a table then using the name of that table as the source for the pivot table, but the pivot table still contained the unfiltered data.  I'm using Excel 2013.  I can't filter the data in the pivot table because the "does not contain" option isn't available for the raw text in the rows.  Copy-pasting the filtered data to a new sheet was the only thing I came up with.